# Altbeacon defaults scan period errors. Anything to be concerned about?

Tags: altbeacon

I have been using the reference app for Altbeacon on various devices and have seen the following errors in the logcat. I am not setting any foreground or background scan timings, I am using a foreground service with bootstrap regions.

Android 8.1 on Nokia 8
Screen off app in background:

Logcat->

```
12-12 13:03:27.156 10226-10226/net.beaconsdkdemo  I/ScanJob: Scan job running for 300000 millis

12-12 13:03:27.159 2277-4762/? E/BtGatt.GattService: App 'net.beaconsdkdemo  ' is scanning too frequently

12-12 13:04:53.335 2277-4762/? E/BtGatt.GattService: App 'net.beaconsdkdemo  ' is scanning too frequently

12-12 13:05:01.628 2277-4762/? E/BtGatt.GattService: App 'net.beaconsdkdemo  ' is scanning too frequently

12-12 13:05:06.596 2277-4762/? E/BtGatt.GattService: App 'net.beaconsdkdemo  ' is scanning too frequently

12-12 13:08:27.374 10226-10226/net.beaconsdkdemo I/ScanJob: Scan job running for 300000 millis

12-12 13:08:27.377 2277-2290/? E/BtGatt.GattService: App 'net.beaconsdkdemo' is scanning too frequently

12-12 13:10:13.493 2277-2615/? E/BtGatt.GattService: App 'net.beaconsdkdemo' is scanning too frequently

12-12 13:15:13.661 2277-2615/? E/BtGatt.GattService: App 'net.beaconsdkdemo' is scanning too frequently

12-12 13:15:21.623 2277-2615/? E/BtGatt.GattService: App 'net.beaconsdkdemo' is scanning too frequently

12-12 13:15:26.928 2277-2615/? E/BtGatt.GattService: App 'net.beaconsdkdemo' is scanning too frequently
```

App opened and running in foreground:

Logcat->

```
2-12 13:20:04.391 10226-10226/net.beaconsdkdemo I/BeaconService: set scan intervals received

12-12 13:20:04.393 10226-10226/net.beaconsdkdemo I/CycledLeScanner: Adjusted nextScanStartTime to be Wed Dec 12 13:15:21 GMT+11:00 2018

12-12 13:20:13.848 2277-2615/? E/BtGatt.GattService: App 'net.beaconsdkdemo' is scanning too frequently

12-12 13:20:46.932 2277-4762/? E/BtGatt.GattService: App 'net.beaconsdkdemo' is scanning too frequently

12-12 13:20:51.345 2277-4762/? E/BtGatt.GattService: App 'net.beaconsdkdemo' is scanning too frequently

12-12 13:20:53.556 2277-2615/? E/BtGatt.GattService: App 'net.beaconsdkdemo' is scanning too frequently

12-12 13:21:06.829 2277-2290/? E/BtGatt.GattService: App 'net.beaconsdkdemo' is scanning too frequently

12-12 13:21:20.099 2277-2290/? E/BtGatt.GattService: App 'net.beaconsdkdemo' is scanning too frequently
```

Android 6 on Samsung Galaxy Mini 5

Logcat->

```
12-12 13:01:59.480 3390-3559/? E/BtGatt.GattService: [GSIM LOG]: gsimLogHandler: net.beaconsdkdemo, msg: MESSAGE_STOP_SCAN

12-12 13:02:01.595 26097-26097/net.beaconsdkdemo E/CycledLeScannerForLollipop: Scan failed: app cannot be registered
```

Are the "Scanning too frequently" entries for Android 8 an indication that the app will be at some point killed?

What's with the scan nextScanStartTime time being in the past?

```
12-12 13:20:04.393 10226-10226/net.beaconsdkdemo I/CycledLeScanner: Adjusted nextScanStartTime to be Wed Dec 12 13:15:21 GMT+11:00 2018
```

Is the "Scan failed: app cannot be registered" for Android 6 due to my app configuration or is it a bluetooth glitch?

I notice that on Android 8, after a period of time, the service is killed and not restarted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a long discussion of this issue [here](https://github.com/AltBeacon/android-beacon-library/issues/554).

A summary of what we know: This log line appears to be caused by a Huawei-specific customization to Android.  The specifics are proprietary and unpublished, so we have only been able to minimally reverse-engineer what is going on.  The basic idea is that Huawei has added some code that monitors the number of scans initiated in the background and starts blocking those scans if the number started exceeds some unpublished threshold in certain unknown conditions.

While **this is only known to affect certain Huawei devices**, There are consequences to seeing this log message.  Scans will basically be blocked when you see this.

If you are using a foreground service with default scan settings, those scan settings will scan at a rate of 1100 ms on, then off for 0 ms, meaning that scanning gets restarted every 1100ms.  Once you detect the same beacon twice in a 1100ms period, this cycling will turn off and the scan will remain on constantly, which should cause these log messages to disappear.  So if your app starts up scanning when beacons are around, this probably won't happen on Huawei.  But if it starts up when beacons are not around it will.

Currently, there is no known workaround for this problem, as even scans once every 15 minutes will trigger this error messages on Huawei devices.  It seems beacon scanning with the screen of is simply unreliable on Huawei devices.

It may be worth trying to whitelist your app against battery optimizations to see if this helps.  If you find any new information, please post on the [library discussion thread](https://github.com/AltBeacon/android-beacon-library/issues/554).

Comment: Thanks for the information. You say that this is Huawei specific but I am seeing it for a Nokia? On my other question, is there any concern/bug for the nextScanStartTime being 5 minutes in the past?

Comment: I am surprised to hear you are seeing this on Nokia, which usually run stock Android.  There is a similar issue with a restriction added in Android 7, the iibrary already handles this since 2.12.1.  This may be worth opening a new issue on the library's GitHub repo showing your setup code and log.

Comment: Thanks. I will mark this as answered as it is "of concern" :)